# how to search - if inputted value is assign me then search for the specific column from DB that have null values (laravel 8)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I need , if someone search in the textbox "Assign Me" keyword then query must show the result where the class_id columns have no value that is null

```
  if (!empty($searchInput)) {
            $exam->join('class', 'students.class_id', '=', 'class.id');
            $exam->join('sections', 'students.section_id', '=', 'sections.id');
           
            $exam->where("class.no", "like", "%$searchInput%")
                 ->orWhere("section.name", "like", "%$searchInput%");          
            $exam->select('students.*','class.no','section.name');
        }
if (!empty($searchInput) && $searchInput == 'Assign Me') {
            $exam->whereNull('class_id');
            $exam->select('class_id');
        }
```

> i tried this but didnt worked  :

```
if (!empty($searchInput) && $searchInput == 'Assign Me') {
                $exam->whereNull('class_id');
                $exam->select('class_id');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!empty($searchInput)) {
    $exam->join('class', 'students.class_id', '=', 'class.id');
    $exam->join('sections', 'students.section_id', '=', 'sections.id');

    if ($searchInput == 'Assign Me') {
        $exam->whereNull('class_id');
    } else {
        $exam->where("class.no", "like", "%$searchInput%")
             ->orWhere("section.name", "like", "%$searchInput%");
    }

    $exam->whereNull('students.show');
    $exam->select('students.*', 'class.no', 'section.name');
}
```